# Reconciling the Rashbam's understanding for leaning left with the anatomy of the throat

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, science, parts-of-the-body, heseiba-leaning

The Gemara ([Pesachim 108a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.108a.9)) rules:

> פרקדן לא שמיה הסיבה הסיבת ימין לא שמה הסיבה ולא עוד אלא שמא יקדים קנה לוושט ויבא לידי סכנה
>
> Lying prone is not called leaning. Leaning right is not called leaning. Furthermore, the trachea might come before the esophagus and he will come to a danger.

[Rashbam ad. loc.](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashbam_on_Pesachim_108a.9.3) first proposes that the issue of danger is when one is lying prone, but he then proposes a second understanding (followed l'halacha by the [Mishnah Berurah 472:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.472.10) with a practical difference for lefties at the Seder) in which this last line refers to the second clause, regarding leaning right:

> דושט הוי על (דרך) ימין ונפתח הכובע שעל פי הקנה מאיליו כשהוא מטה כלפי ימין ואם יכנס בו המאכל הרי סכנה שאין אוכלין ומשקין נכנסין אלא דרך הושט
>
> The esophagus is to the right, and when one leans to the right the epiglottis will open from the windpipe. If food enters [the windpipe], there will be a danger, for food and drink only pass through the esophagus.

How can Rashbam say that the trachea is to the left and the esophagus to the right, when the trachea is to the front, and the esophagus is to the back? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharynx) has a nice diagram, but you can tell for yourself by pressing gently on the front of your throat: the hard rings you'll feel are the outer lining of your trachea.

How can Rashbam posit that this line refers specifically to leaning to the right, when it contradicts very obvious anatomical facts?

Comment: I have other problems with the Mishnah Berurah, but I'd like to figure out anatomically what he's referring to before I discuss my other issues, which are physiological in nature and made much more difficult by the presence of four cups of alcohol.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an answer other than that he was not aware of the anatomical facts? Note the Radvaz already raises the anatomical question on the Rashbam.

Comment: @Alex Yes. The relevant anatomical facts are just too obvious for me to accept that he was not aware of them. If the Radvaz gives an answer besides Rashi fits better, please share!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this quite answers your question, but [Radvaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) ([3:584 (1012)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_3.1012?lang=he)) does seem to question Rashbam's anatomical facts, and says something that might be considered an answer:

> ועוד ראיתי כי הסימנים שוכבין זה על זה ולא ידעתי אם סימני אדם נשתנה

Depending on how you read this, he could be entertaining the possibility that the anatomical facts had changed over time. What might have been anatomically true in the times of Rashbam (or Chazal) may have no longer been true.

Comment: I'm reading the line without any context, but I would have read סימני אדם נשתנה (human signs are different from animals signs), not humans changing over time (maybe this is what you mean by "depending on how you read this")

Comment: @ba That is precisely what I meant by “depending on how you read it”.

Comment: @ba A) Why would Chazal be discussing animal anatomy in this context? B) As far as I can tell, bovine, equestrian, canine, and human pharynxes (couldn't find anything on other animals in my quick search), while all distinct from one another, all share that the trachea is in front and the esophagus in back. Chazal surely knew how animal throats are structured given their role in Shechitah.

Comment: @DonielF The point is that it’s not clear if the ראיתי was on an animal or a person.

Comment: @Alex cc ^^. Extending this further, with such diversity among different creatures, which all have different methods of eating (chewing cud vs. not) and all have different diets (carnivorous, herbivorous, omnivorous), yet they all have the exact same structure with regards to the trachea and esophagus makes it difficult for me to accept that this changed over time in humans specifically. If ראיתי refers to animals, and he's not clear on if humans are different...again, just push gently on the front of your throat. It's not too hard to check.

Comment: A) Chazal weren't discussing animals. The Radvaz only brings it as a relevant fact. B) Which is apparently what the Radvaz brought this fact to show. C) This is essentially the same as the question on the Rashbam, and the Radvaz seems to be cautiously rejecting his view that the esophagus is on the right

Comment: @ba [There are two sets of numberings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgbpV.jpg)

Comment: @Alex Then maybe this presentation is better?

Comment: @ba Sure. I wasn’t objecting to the edit. Just pointing out לקושטא דמילתא.

Comment: @DonielF Note that Radvaz could be criticizing Rashbam’s anatomy without criticizing Chazal. He could just say that Rashbam’s peshat is wrong.

Comment: @Alex Certainly. I have no problems anatomically with Rashi's understanding of the Gemara.

Comment: @ba Then the Radvaz doesn't actually answer the question at hand.

Comment: @DonielF Indeed, if he’s referring to animals then you have the same question on him as on Rashbam.